# Modifying a whole list of nouns by attaching modifier to the first noun only

Tags: nouns, lists, modifiers, ellipses

With sentences like:

> I visited the parks in the area, museums, and shops.

> We enjoyed dancing on our wedding day, chatting to guests, and listening to the band.

> He spoke to all the boys in the school, the girls, and even the teachers.

My contention is that most English speakers would take the meaning to be as follows:

> I visited the parks in the area, museums (in the area), and shops (in the area).

> We enjoyed dancing on our wedding day, chatting to guests (on our wedding day), and listening to the band (on our wedding day).

> He spoke to all the boys in the school, the girls (in the school), and even the teachers (in the school).

Am I correct in my assumption? Is it safe to say that in English, a modifier attached to the first noun in a list sometimes modifies the entire list?

I suppose that ideally we would rewrite sentences like this to remove any ambiguity, but let us say that for whatever reason, we cannot do so. Is it acceptable? Is it bad grammar but likely to be understood? Or is it completely incorrect and likely to be misunderstood?

Perhaps this is related to ellipsis? The Chicago Manual of Style has the example:

> One lump or two?

Which the listener interprets as:

> (Do you want) One lump or two (lumps)?

Do you think it is related? Or is this a separate issue?

My feeling is that this type of clause is not ideal but acceptable, although I have been unable to find any references, articles, or even forum posts that provide a good answer to the topic. If you are able to give me any references (e.g. the rule number in the Chicago Manual of Style) or tell me what terms to search for to find the answer to this question, I would be very grateful indeed! Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 'I visited the parks in the area, museums, and shops.' sounds more natural as 'I visited the parks in the area, the museums, and the shops.' It's difficult to pinpoint the meaning of 'all the boys' ... / ... 'the girls' (the scope of 'all').  But I'd agree with your analysis here ... though more ambiguous sentences soon become possible. 'For entertainment, we go to Old Trafford when we can afford it, to local stately homes, to the local museums, and to the theatre.'

Comment: Thank you for your input @EdwinAshworth - much appreciated! I agree that your revised version of the first sentence sounds more natural, and certainly agree that your final example is more ambiguous.

Comment: I think it's misleading to characterise, for example, ***in the area*** in #1 as *specifically* modifying the np ***the parks***. It seems to me it's more of a "sentence / clause" adverb that attaches to the entire statement ***I visited the parks***. Which by the time-honoured principle of "deletion of predictably repeated elements" means we can assume *I visited the parks in the area, [I visited] [the] **museums** [in the area], **and** [I visited] [the] **shops** [in the area].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your comment! That's very interesting and an angle I hadn't considered. It makes sense though. Perhaps you are right. Let me think about the issue more from this perspective. I'm interested to see if anyone will build on it and offer supporting or contradicting examples.